# Is it possible to have BBox's on labels in Altair?

Tags: python, altair

I have a chart similar to this but with less data points.

1. I want to add BBox's to the labels ideally
2. As a bonus question how would If I had this many labels would I only display a certain number of them?

```
line = (alt.Chart(source)
        .mark_line(point=True)
        .encode(x=alt.X("date"),
                y=alt.Y("price"),
                color=alt.Color("symbol", legend=alt.Legend(orient="top"))
                )
).properties(width=1000)

labels = (line
          .mark_text(baseline='middle', yOffset=-15, fontWeight='bold', fill='black')
          .encode(text=alt.Text('price', format='.1f'),
                  color=alt.value("black"),
                  )
)

line + labels
```

I have found this in the altair API ducmentation but I am unsure as to how to pass it in.

https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.BBox.html